# How to do a proper redirect to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

First of all can this affect SEO rankings?

Here is what I used, but I get a loop based on tihs site

https://httpstatus.io/

here is the htaccess code...is it written correctly?

```html
# Use PHP56 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56s .php
# Changed PHP handler from application/x-httpd-php54s to application/x-httpd-phpbetas on Mon Jan 11 12:15:36 MST 2016.

# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymlinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^badbreathhalitosis.com [nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.badbreathhalitosis.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$


RewriteRule (.*) https://www.badbreathhalitosis.com/phpBB2/ [R=301,L]
```

Also I wantt it to redirect to https with www only

Comment: to redirect to https only

Comment: cause i need to redirect to subfolder....cause that is where the forum is....no files are in the root